# How to assign a variable to the number of used rows

Tags: excel, vba

I want to take data from two departments and put them in the same sheet to use for pivot tables.

The data is automatically separated onto different sheets by departments when I run the report. The amount of data (rows used) changes.

I am trying to store a count of used rows for each department.

Is it possible to use a variable to go to a specific row?

An example would be, if 213 rows are used by the first department then I want to paste the second department's data on row 214 to not overlap/miss any data for the pivot tables.

With this

```
Dim lastRow30A As Long
lastRow30A.Value = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

I get

> compile error
> invalid or unqualified reference

and the `.Rows` in line 2 is highlighted.

With this

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.count

Dim count30A As Long

count30A = Selection.count
```

I get

> Run-time error '438':
> Object doesn't support this property or method.

The line `Selection.count` is highlighted.

Comment: `lastRow30A = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`   A `Long` variable has no properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using this in a `With` block, but if you're not then it needs to be.

Also, drop the `.Value`: a `Long` variable has no properties or methods.

```
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow30A = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: Will that With block make it so I can use the variable later in another sheet?

Comment: The with block only plays a part in assigning the variable - I don't know anything about the scope of your variables or what you mean by "use it in another sheet" or "later".  If `lastRow30A` is declared within a procedure then it's only accessible within that procedure: if you need to use it somewhere else later then you'd need to declare it at the top of your module, outside of any Sub/Function.

Comment: I took your advice and changed some things around. I'm trying the following and got the run-time error of 438. 

```With ActiveSheet
    Dim lastRow30A As Long

    lastRow30A = [Sheet1].Range("A1048576").Selection.End(xlUp).Row(1)

End With``` 
Sorry, the code doesnt come out looking so good on the comments, but that's made up of 4 separate lines, and not just one big line

Comment: What is `[Sheet1]` here?

Comment: It is just a new sheet that will be renamed to "Total" later after all of the data is in the same sheet.

Comment: `Sheet1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row` no need for square brackets here (and that notation is generally best avoided I think)